# Не выводится информация при подгрузке через AJAX в Опере, Яндекс браузере, Эксплорере и Эдже

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Делаю Онлайн-Консультант для чата. Сообщения у пользователя каждые 2 секунды подгружаются через AJAX (не надо мне кричать, что так уже не делают, я знаю). Так вот, использую скрипт:

```
  function show() {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "<?bloginfo('template_url');?>/load_messes.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#result_div_id").html(html); 
                $i++;
            }  
        });  
    }  


    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',2000);  
    });
```

А вот код обновления сообщений (load_messes.php):

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); @ini_set('error_reporting',0);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-blog-header.php');
global $wpdb;
?>
<?php
$_SESSION['session'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$_SESSION['session'] .= session_id();
$session = $_SESSION['session'];
$messages = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT *
    FROM euro_messages
    WHERE SESSION =  "'.$session.'"
');
$seen = $wpdb->get_var('
    SELECT id
    FROM euro_messages
    WHERE SESSION =  "'.$session.'" and seen = 0
'); 
$seen_2 = $wpdb->get_var('
    SELECT id
    FROM euro_messages
    WHERE SESSION =  "'.$session.'" and seen = 0 and fromto > 0
'); 
$templatepath = get_bloginfo('template_url');
if($seen){
    echo '<script>
            $(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var $container = $(\'.container\');
                    $container[0].scrollTop = $container[0].scrollHeight;
                }, 100);
            });
        </script>';
}
if($seen_2){
    echo '  
        <script>
            setTimeout(function soundClick() {
                var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
                audio.src = \''.$templatepath.'/sounds/sms.mp3\'; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
                audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
            }, 100);
        </script> ';
}
for ( $d = 0; $d < count($messages); $d++) {
    $mess = $messages[$d]->message;
    $fromto = $messages[$d]->fromto;
    if($fromto == 0){
        $mess_text = "<h4 style='margin:0;padding:0;'>Вы:</h4><font size=2>$mess</font><hr>";
    }else{
        $mess_text = "<h4 style='margin:0;padding:0;'>Консультант:</h4><font size=2>$mess</font><hr>";
    }
    echo $mess_text;
    $wpdb->update( 
        'euro_messages',
        array( 'seen' => 1 ),
        array( 'session' => $session )
    );
}
if(!$messages){
    echo '<font size=2 style="text-align: left;">   
    <i>
        Для начала диалога отправьте сообщение.
    </i>
    </font> ';
}
?>
```

Сайт у меня стоит на вп. Кода отправляю сообщение, идет по-сути, тот же скрипт, только там идет подгрузка другого файла - form.php. В него передается сообщение пользователя и оно дабавляется в бд. А вот вывод load_messes.php почему-то работает только в Хроме. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: load_messes.php или load-messes.php? Код у Вас в вопросе простой, предполагая, что вокруг него все нормально, например, `$i` где-то объявлена и инициализирована, все должно работать. Добавьте `consol.log($i + ": " + html);` в `success`.

Comment: $i инициализирована там гораздо ранее и нужна вообще не для этого скрипта, к нему никакого отношения не имеет) - она нужна для того, чтобы автоматом опускать сообщения вниз - смотрите сами: var $i = 0;
    function show()  
    {  
     $.ajax({  
      url: "<?bloginfo('template_url');?>/load_messes.php",  
      cache: false,  
      success: function(html){  
       $("#result_div_id").html(html); 
       $i++;
      }  
     });  
    }  
    
     
---продолжение в комментарии ниже---

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){  
     show();  
     setInterval('show()',2000);  
    });  
    
   </script>  
   <script>
    $(function () {
     setInterval(function () {
      if($i == 1){
       var $container = $('.container');
       $container[0].scrollTop = $container[0].scrollHeight;
       $i++;
      }
     }, 100);
    });
   </script>

Comment: возможно не работает из-за того, что сайт стоит на локалке, так как сделал на своем другом сайте (стоит на хосте) аналогичную структуру в файле - все получилось и в хроме, и в опере))

Comment: Чую функция show в `<script></script>`. Скорее всего не правильный url. `url: "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/load_messes.php",` или `url: "<?=bloginfo('template_url');?>/load_messes.php",`

Comment: @Doofy, Если бы был неправильный url, то Хром бы тоже не открывал, show - не более, чем название функции)) Также, это же не единственный прописанный у меня на сайте урл - другие же файлы работают

Comment: Я где-то писал, что так делать очень плохо. Лучше `setTimeout` в `complete: function()`. Запрос может задержаться или не успеет прийти, как отправится следующий

Comment: @Doofy, я тоже про это подумал, поставил таймер аж на 10 секунд - все равно не срабатывает, хотя там файл элементарный. Дело тут не в этом,  не работает именно вывод из файла инфы - если прописать в файле SQL-запрос, то он, как ни странно, выполняется - то есть Опера и тд и тп выполняют этот файл. Пробовал и setTimeout - бесполезно, даже Хром перестал выполнять - конечно, кроссбраузерность достигнута, но цель не в этом))

Comment: А где вывод инфы из файла? Если сам запрос работает, нужно искать причину в другом месте, а в вопросе нет данных для размышления

Comment: @Doofy, Сейчас добавлю его в вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Используй complete:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
});

function show() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?= bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/load_messes.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#result_div_id").html(html); 
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(show, 2000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Это что, объясняет, почему работает только в Хроме?

Comment: Перестало работать даже в Хроме)

Comment: Про другие браузер сказать нечего - все стоит колом

Comment: Отлично, теперь значит, все браузеры ведут себя одинаково, что и требовалось :)

Comment: @Igor, да, теперь стало гораздо лучше xD))

Comment: @Dan eStet Перестало работать потому что в строке $("#result_div_id").html(html); ошибка. Необходимо $("#result_div_id").html(data);

Comment: @Igor не объясняет, я описал рабочую логику для задачи.